# Why isn't `chmod` command functioning in Kali Linux 2020?

Tags: bash, permissions, kali-linux

I am basically really new at Kali and I have no previous experience in other OS other than Windows. I am trying to learn Kali using various tutorials on Youtube and I was basically learning ipsweep (I think it is called that only ) using `.sh` file programmed in `/bin/bash`, i tried to make a file executable in root using the

```
chmod -x filename.sh
sudo chmod -x filename.sh
chmod -rwx filename.sh
```

I thought I didn't have enough permissions because it showed no bash error but when i tried `./filename.sh` it said `permission denied`. Then I saw if the file is executable or not but it showed something rather strange: it showed that the `chmod` command wasn't even executed (I think i am still very bad at understanding this). How to do this right?

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) - in short, kali is not for beginners.

Comment: I answered your question but I fully support the above comment. The mistake you made could be done in *any* Linux distro. The point is in Kali a beginner's experience will probably get *worse*.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: `man chmod`

Answer (score 2):

`chmod -x` *removes* the execute permission. If you want to make the file executable you need `+x`:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Furthermore the file needs to be readable (`chmod +r filename.sh`). With `chmod -rwx filename.sh` you have removed all the permissions, including this one. The dashes (which are displayed in your terminal as one long line) in the output of `ls -l` [indicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/108618) `chmod` worked perfectly.